# Elasticsearch attachment plugin vs own tika implementation

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika

I want to use the Tika toolkit to index content of documents files (pdf, docx...) and images (via tesseract plugin).

I tried elastic ingest attachment plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html) it works pretty good but without OCR build-in.
And I have to send base64 of my file, so high memory usage + elastic index the "data" (base64) field which is useless.

I'm thinking of using directly Tika toolkit and then index the content in ElasticSearch.

So I'm wondering if it's a better way or not ?

Comment: You're right! I've collected all the issues in one post [Ingest Attachment Plugin for ElasticSearch: Should You Use It?](https://blog.ambar.cloud/ingest-attachment-plugin-for-elasticsearch-should-you-use-it/)

Answer (score 4):

We've created a system to process files (Crawl -> OCR -> Index -> Search). It's called [Ambar](https://ambar.cloud). We built it with idea to create a good and solid replacement for Ingest Attachment.

As a search engine we use ElasticSearch, as a context extractor: Tika + Tesseract + ImageMagick + Custom extractors for PDF.

We made it to provide a simple, but yet powerful alternative to own Tika + ES implementation.

Check out [Github](https://github.com/RD17/ambar) to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, there is little to no documentation about enabling OCR via Tesseract in the `elasticsearch-mapper-attachments` plugin.

Everything is pointing to you handling the task of OCR outside of Elasticsearch, and then indexing the content separately.

Reference: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/issues/10